# Current approach to reflect dynamic data from json in nodejs using setInterval

Tags: node.js, dynamic-data

I am trying to develop a MERN stack application, and I have done numerous attempts at this. So, what I am trying to achieve is have some data I am pulling from an api and dump it to a database, then query from the database to create a JSON file every 5 minutes(using jenkins and python, the best approach I can think of). Below is a method I am implementing and it does not work. If I remove the setInterval() function and un-comment the callback function, the code works but does not update the data.

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

// Read JSON File
function readJSON(callback) {
    fs.readFile('./name.json', "utf8", function(err, result) {
        if (err) callback (err);
        callback(JSON.parse(result));
    });
}

// Process JSON File during callback
// readJSON(function(res) {
//     app.get('/api/customers', (request, response) => {
//         response.json(res);
//     });
// });

// Attempt to run every 5 minutes
setInterval(readJSON(function(res) {
    app.get('/api/customers', (request, response) => {
        response.json(res);
})}, 60000 * 5); // 5 Minutes

const port = 5000

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

I thought of using sockets, but I don't want it to be real-time, only live data on an interval. Restful API's I don't believe are a good fit here either, I don't want a 2-way communication to modify/update the data. If my approach is bad, please let me know why you'd pick another approach. I am just trying to establish a foundation in full-stack web dev. Thanks!

Comment: app.get is how you define an API... so, what you're doing is opening the same API every 5 minutes after readJSON is done. I'm not sure what you want to do, but this code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Shl ah, ok. So, I was trying to do is send the new data (refresh the api) then use setInterval in my react code to retrieve the new values every 5 minutes (dynamic data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A logical code would be:

On server side:

```
function readJSON(callback) {
    fs.readFile('./name.json', "utf8", function(err, result) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        callback(null, JSON.parse(result));
    });
}

app.get('/api/customers', (request, response) => {
    readJSON((err, nameContent) => {
        if(err) {
            response.status(500).send(err);
        }
        response.send(nameContent);
    })
});
```

And in the client side ask for the data every 5 minutes:

```
someAjaxMethod('/api/customers', (err, nameContent) => console.log(err, nameContent));
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work, so whenever the json file changes, it'll update the local api? Also, this approach I am taking for dynamic data, is it a viable one or is there a better way to do such a thing?

Comment: this is actually a bad way to get the data once it changes. In order to fetch the data when it changes the client should listen to changes on server side. This can be achieved by using WebSocket. Here is a link to some common implementation of this. [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket).